# Each rotation to landscape requires reload

Tags: css, iphone, rotation

Search done. Nothing in the archives like this. I've screwed up a previously working site. I know not how. Specifically, rotating my iPhone 6 from portrait to landscape displays my site narrowed to about 50%. Reloading pops it out to normal presentation. Rotating back to portrait, and then returning to landscape, requires another reload. Never had a problem where all viewports work yet a kick in the ass required after a rotation. Site is CodeStruggle dot com. I have the small and medium backgrounds set to tan and pink for trouble shooting. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. For some reason my horizontal rule would not work. So I substituted the creature below until I could investigate the `<hr>` problem. Everything performed perfectly on desktop, but not on my phone. Live and learn.

```
<p class='fake-horizontal-rule'>_________________________________________________________</p>

p.fake-horizontal-rule{
color:#ccc;
text-align:center;
}
```